# Visual Studio 2013 throws error after installing Oracle Developer Tools for VS2013

Tags: c#, oracle, selenium, visual-studio-2013, oracle11g

I am trying to make a connection with Oracle db using Selenium scripting.For same installed Oracle Developer Tools for VS2013. After installation error is shown as below:

[image]

Can someone help in troubleshooting it. I am relatively new to C# and .NET and Oracle.

System info:
Windows 7 Enterprise , 32 bit OS
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 
Oracle Client Version 12.1.0.2.0
MS Visual Studio 2013

Comment: I'd recommend you uninstall everything, clear your GAC (if the uninstall doesn't take care of that), and then install a clean version

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hambone!!! I am able to resolve the warning by removing oracle data provider dll file from gac.